# Are layers referencing another image contained in the final image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

When I create an image from a Dockerfile which starts with a `FROM` clause, is the corresponding layer embedded in the resulting image or does the resulting image only contain a reference to the remote base image layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's embedded, otherwise the docker image would break if the upstream image ever changed. When you run docker build, you are taking a point in time snapshot of that layer and including it.